# How to get trigger text correctly in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database-trigger

Given:

```
CREATE TABLE X (Id INT)
GO
CREATE TRIGGER Y ON X FOR DELETE AS SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO
sp_rename 'X', 'Z'
GO
SELECT sm.definition v1, OBJECT_DEFINITION(t.object_id) v2, c.text v3
FROM sys.triggers t
JOIN sys.sql_modules sm ON t.object_id = sm.object_id AND t.Name = 'Y'
JOIN sys.syscomments c ON t.object_id = c.id
GO
sp_helptext 'Y'
```

This simple query creates a table, puts a trigger on it, renames the table and uses four different ways to obtain the text of the trigger:

1. `sys.sql_modules` view
2. `sys.syscomments` view
3. `OBJECT_DEFINITION` function
4. `sp_helptext` function

All the four ways yield the same text for the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Y ON X FOR DELETE AS SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

And that is my problem, of course, because this text cannot be used to create the trigger - table `X` no longer exists.

Now, if I select the trigger in the SSMS (on table Z, of course) and script the CREATE action, here is what I get:

```
USE [mydb]
GO

/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[Y]    Script Date: 12/22/2017 10:32:22 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Y] ON [dbo].[Z] FOR DELETE AS SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Z] ENABLE TRIGGER [Y]
GO
```

Which is correct, unlike the previous 4 ways.

So, my question is - how do I obtain the correct trigger text? The one we can run to recreate the trigger. Like SSMS does.

Comment: Note: all those ways will give you actual text of the *SQL definition statement*, and not the current script of your trigger. - Possible related to [Update syscomments text field](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21457398/Update-syscomments-text-field.html) ;).

Answer (score 2):

SSMS uses SMO for scripting, which changes the ON clause of the `CREATE TRIGGER` to match that of the parent table. You could use a SMO PowerShell script like the example below to get the same text as SSMS generates. Just tweak the PS script for the generation options you want.

The trigger text apparently got out of sync because the table was renamed without recreating the trigger.

```
try {

    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll";

    $sqlServerName = "YourServer";
    $databaseName = "YourDatabase";

    $scriptPath = "c:\temp\Z_TriggerScripts.sql";

    $SMOserver = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($sqlServerName);
    $scriptr = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter') ($SMOserver);

    $database = $SMOserver.databases[$databaseName]

    $objectsToScript = @();
    $objectsToScript += $database.Tables["Z"].Triggers;

    $scriptr.Options.FileName = $scriptPath;
    $scriptr.Options.AnsiFile = $false;
    $scriptr.Options.AllowSystemObjects = $false;
    $scriptr.Options.IncludeIfNotExists = $false;
    $scriptr.Options.NoCommandTerminator = $false;
    $scriptr.Options.ScriptBatchTerminator = $true;

    $null = $scriptr.Script($objectsToScript);

}
catch [Exception] {
    $e = $_.Exception
    $e.ToString();
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Are we supposed to recreate the triggers when we rename the parent table? Is it the best practice?

Comment: In other words, there is no way in SQL to get the correct trigger text? Only from code?

Comment: @mark, AFAIK you can't transform the trigger text from T-SQL the way SMO/SSDT does. What is your use-case for needing to do that? Yes, it's a best practice to be mindful of modules when renaming objects, hence the warning raised by `sp_rename` "Caution: Changing any part of an object name could break scripts and stored procedures." Unfortunately, the SSMS GUI suppresses that message.

Comment: This is a little bit different. The trigger is not broken when the table is renamed, unless it references the table in the trigger code. But, if the table is not referenced, then the trigger works fine, even though its definition text is now broken.